# Find the count of EMPTY or NULL columns in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have around 30 columns in a MySQL table.  I want to calculate how many column fields for a particular row are empty. This table is for storing user information.  I want to find out how many profile fields (such as 'Name', 'Age', 'Location' - all of which are stored in a separate column) are empty/haven't been filled in by the user.

The columns I want to refine down are the final 20 columns (because the first 10 columns store stuff like User IDs, passwords, etc. - I only want the final 20 columns which store profile information). How do I find out the AMOUNT of empty/NULL columns in this table?

Comment: if you give a tabular example of the data you expect to see, it will be easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the idea is to get a result something like this:

```
col       emp    
------    ------    
FName        15  
LName         2  
Age          22
```

..use:

```
SELECT 'FName' AS col, SUM(CASE FName IS NULL || FName='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as emp FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT 'LName' AS col, SUM(CASE LName IS NULL || LName='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as emp FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT 'Age' AS col, SUM(CASE Age IS NULL || Age='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as emp FROM MyTable
```

...or:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE t.fname IS NULL OR t.fname = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fname_count,
       SUM(CASE t.lname IS NULL OR t.lname = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lname_count,
       SUM(CASE t.age IS NULL OR t.age = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS age_count
  FROM MYTABLE t
```

Comment: +1: But you could use a single statement, just alias the column with the name of the column being checked.

Comment: Thats exactly how I would have handled similar conditional testing... Not just an empty value, but explicit test for NULL too

Comment: "for a particular row" - This will show the totals for all rows.

Comment: I want to find out the amount of columns with NULL or a value of '' for a particular row (i.e. for one user)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I know I'm going to kick myself I see what you mean, but I'm having a total brain blockage here.  Could you post an example, please?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: here's me kicking myself. yurghh. Thanks!

Comment: You had the meat of the query, that's what really matters.

Answer (score 4):

You can compute it like this:

```
SELECT SUM((`Name` = '') + (`Age` = 0) + (`Location` = '' OR `Location` IS NULL) + ...)
```

You didn't specify what types of columns you have so I used different comparing methods to illustrate the point. As a general idea you should compare to see if a specific column value is equal to the default value for that field (i.e. field not specified by the user). Use `= ''` for strings, `= 0` for numbers, `IS NULL` for columns that have default NULL etc. You could also combine checks for NULL and empty value if you want. It all depends on what you want to find out.

Of course, as dnagirl pointed out in her answer, you should test for both empty and NULL values, but that really depends on how your columns are defined and also if you consider empty values to be filled or not. The point I was trying to make is that you can use `SUM` to add up boolean expression results.

**EDIT:** Didn't notice that you wanted for each row. Just remove the `SUM` and you'll get it per row.

Comment: Is there any way to automate this? Otherwise I'll have to list over twenty column names to find NULL values

Comment: @Jamie: if you're going to run this again and again, write a stored procedure.  Yes, you'll still have to list all the columns, but you'll only have to type it once.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it you have a table such as

```
id | FName | LName  | Age
1  | John  | ""     | NULL
2  | Mary  | Simons | NULL
```

And you want: row 1 has 2 empty/null fields, and row 2 has 1 empty/null fields

```
SELECT
    id,

    IF (FName IS NULL OR FName = '', 1, 0) + 
    IF (LName IS NULL OR LName = '', 1, 0) + 
    IF (Age IS NULL OR Age = '', 1, 0)
    as empty_field_count
```

Though now that I've written this I see Saul's response, I think that may have better performance that this solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @dnagirl answered, I would consider doing an extra step... adding a column to the table for "anyNulls".  And set it as a flag for ANY empty/null values, so you would be able to quickly query those that need to be completed for data requirements instead of just how many of each category.  One record could have all fields missing vs one column in multiple rows that need to be fixed.