# Select userids from mysql table if user has at least 3 fields filled

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql user table that holds user data like that:

```
userid | title     | content
----------------------------------
1      | about     | I am from ...
1      | location  | Norway
1      | name      | Mark
1      | website   | 
2      | about     | 
2      | location  | 
2      | name      | 
2      | website   | 
3      | ...
```

As you see the `content` is empty for userid 2, and also for many more users in the table.

My goal is to select only the userids that have **at least 3 fields filled**. All others should be ignored.

As my mysql knowledge is still weak I could not find a solution for this. I only found the opposite and just with count: [Find the count of EMPTY or NULL columns in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045175/find-the-count-of-empty-or-null-columns-in-a-mysql-table)

What is the magic mysql query? Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use aggregation and a `having` clause for this:

```
select u.userId
from users u
where content > '' and content is not null
group by u.userId
having count(*) >= 3;
```

I added the non-blank check as well as the `null` check.  The `null` check is redundant, but it makes the intention clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your lightning fast *magic* answer :) It works. Only thing I had to change was `where content > ''` (as content is an empty string). Thanks a lot!