# In Mysql how do I count # of blank cells in a row

Tags: mysql

I am wondering how to count the number of times there is an empty cell in a row.

for example

```
|unique|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10|  
|0001  |    |  1 |  1 | 1  |    |    |    |    |  1 |     |  
|0002  |  1 |    |    | 1  | 1  |  1 |    | 1  |    |     |
|0003  |    |  1 |  1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |     |
|0004  |    |    |    | 1  |    |    |    |    |    |     |
|0005  |  1 |    |    | 1  |    |    |  1 |    |    |  1  |
|0006  |    |  1 |  1 | 1  |    |    |    |    |  1 |     |
```

What I want to return is 0001(6), 0002(4), 0003(8), 004(9), 005(6), 006(6)

I just can't seem to figure it out short of pulling all the data and processing it in php or javascript.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `CASE` Statement to get the empty values, then I get the sum of the `col` to `col9`. See Below:

```
SELECT 
      unique,
      (CASE col='' THEN 1 else 0 END
      +
      CASE col1='' THEN 1 else 0 END
      +
      CASE col2='' THEN 1 else 0 END
      +
      CASE col3='' THEN 1 else 0 END
      +
      CASE col4='' THEN 1 else 0 END
      +
      CASE col5='' THEN 1 else 0 END
      +
      CASE col6='' THEN 1 else 0 END
      +
      CASE col7='' THEN 1 else 0 END
      +
      CASE col8='' THEN 1 else 0 END
      +
      CASE col9='' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS CountEmptyCell
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thank you.  I kept getting errors but managed to get the implementation below to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You would use an expression such as this:

```
select unique, (col1 is null) + (col2 is null) + . . .  + (col10 is null)
```

MySQL treats a boolean as an integer in a numeric context, with 1 for true and 0 for false.  So this counts the number of columns that have a `NULL` value.

This can be used to count any values.  So, if by "empty" you mean a `''` rather than `NULL`, then:

```
select unique, (col1 = '') + (col2 = '') + . . .  + (col10 = '')
```

Comment: I managed to get this to work.
I am working on an extremely complicated SQL query with 150 columns and this gets me one step closer to my end result. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
SELECT `unique`,
  SUM(CASE t.`col` IS NULL OR t.`col` = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `col_count`,
  SUM(CASE t.`col1` IS NULL OR t.`col1` = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `col1_count`,
...
...
FROM MYTABLE t
```

This answer is actually implemented for this question([Find the count of EMPTY or NULL columns in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045175/find-the-count-of-empty-or-null-columns-in-a-mysql-table)) by @dnagirl.

Please take a look on this too.

Comment: Anytime, it is great to help you.